# Why is the edit count always wrong now that I crossed 10k rep?

Tags: support, editing, reviews

I recently crossed 10,000 rep. Ever since, there is always something claimed in the editable changes to review. But when I click on that number 3 (or whatever it is on a given day), it takes me to the Review page, like the one shown, where there is often nothing to review (like the one shown). When I was under 10K and there was a edit count showing, that meant there were edits to review. If I ever clicked on it and got nothing, that meant those were my own tag edits. I haven't been editing tags lately. What is the 3 all about? 
[image]

Comment: Related, network wide: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230742/225745

Answer (score 5):

This is because once you cross 10k rep -- the review counter in the statusbar changes to show the amount of reviews in-flight on the site as a whole. (I know, this seems to be one of the most confusing things that happens at 10k rep.)

Comment: Ok... so where do I go to see these reviews? It just seems weird that there's this "3" hanging there in space with no way to see what those 3 are.

Comment: @SRM -- you won't be able to see them if they're not in one of your queues

Comment: @SRM  These tend to be reviews that you've already done (e.g. an edit that still needs a vote to make a decision) or reviews from which you are excluded (e.g. your own tag edits).  You can find the ones that you already did in the history section of the appropriate review queue.  You can find your edits under Activity in your profile.